# Get request text

Tags: c#

I have a `HttpWebRequest`:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(methodUrl.ToString());
req.Method = "POST";
string postData = Serializer.Serialize(GetAllFields());
req.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
req.Accept = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";  
...
```

And I would like to see the actual raw request before it's sent.
(`req.ToString()` only gives the `req`'s type)
I came to conclusion I should use `Stream` somehow, but I can't understand how..

How can I get the my web request's headers and body before it's sent?

**Added:** I ultimately want something like:

```
string requestAsText= //some method that will give me the whole post text.
```

Thanks.

Comment: is using Fiddler not an option?

Comment: @InSane - You may say I'm trying to get Fiddler's output in code (as string value)

Answer (score 2):

Add these to your config file and this will pretty much dump every communication (this saves to network.log file):

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

Comment: Ahh.. I'm not sure I understand what this does. Please refer to my update to see if that's doing what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will save all communication to a file including headers.... just add this to your web.config or app.config file.

Comment: i do not a way and wild be surprised if there is a way apart from fiddler