# How to trace outgoing httpwebrequest

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm sending an HttpWebRequest to a remote server. The remote server is rejecting my request.

How can I capture the raw format of my outgoing request without using wireshark or something like that?

I tried adding Trace="true" TraceMode="SortByTime" to the aspx page, but this appears to capture only incoming requests.

I tried to enable tracing [as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900381/get-request-text), but it doesn't seem to generate a log file anywhere.  Would network.log be in the root of the site?  It's not there and I've searched my computer / the website for it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I use Microsoft Network Monitor (their "Wireshark") for such things. Why do you want to avoid such tools?

Comment: Netmon captures much more data than I needed. Some days it's hard enough to solve the problem at hand, let alone sift through more network layers than needed @UweKeim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use some tool like [Fiddler](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=download%20fiddler&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp&ei=t40iUKO1JYPirAeitIG4AQ&usg=AFQjCNE9h32pBsq5Nv000r2subMLAXwJ4A). You would be able to see the whole packt

Comment: I completely forgot that fiddler would be able to capture requests at this level. I'm used to just using it for browser requests.  Thank you so much @Ankit